# How can I use static_assert to call a function that receives an array as pointer and length?

Tags: c++, static-assert

I have a function that receives an array, and I want to test it using `static_assert()`:

```
// This is the function I want to test:
constexpr static int find_minimum(const int arr[], size_t size);

// the ony way I have found is to define another function:
constexpr static int helper(std::initializer_list<int> lst)
{
    return find_minimum(lst.begin(), lst.size());
}

// and then call:
static_assert(2 == helper({2,3,4}));
```

This works as expected, but is there a way to do this without the helper function?

Comment: It you want to pass a list like `{2,3,4}` then no there's really no other way. But I would rather *overload* the original function instead, like `constexpr static int find_minimum(std::initializer_list<int> lst)`

Comment: As for the `find_minimum` function itself, judging by the name it seems like your own implementation of [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) or [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min).

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achieve? You say you want to test the function that takes an array. but you call it with a helper function that uses an initializer_list.
Why not just using an array directly?

Comment: `static_assert(2 == find_minimum(std::array{2,3,4}.data(), 3));`?

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is define the test array as a `constexpr` variable:

```
constexpr int testarray[] = {2, 3, 4};
static_assert(2 == find_minimum(testarray, sizeof(testarray)));
```

Comment: Any reason for the extra parentheses in `sizeof testarray`?

Comment: not very usefull, as, of course, I want many more tests...

Comment: @DuduArbel Then you specify those variables, perhaps in a fixture / input class together.